# Varnish http accelerator failed

Tags: linux, caching, memcached, varnish, ubuntu-server

I tried to `service varnish start` but it won't start.

```
/etc/init.d/varnish: 33: ulimit: error setting limit (operation not permitted)
/etc/init.d/varnish: 36: ulimit: error setting limit (operation not permitted)
 * Starting HTTP accelerator varnishd    [fail]
/var/run/varnishd.pid: permission denied
```

Comment: It seems that varnish startup script is trying to set the ulimit but it is not able to set it though which user you are trying to start the service and which OS you are using. Can you try starting the service with root user or use sudo privileges.

Comment: thx for the help, I recheck the varnish configuration and found that the varnish already start after booting. @linux_fanatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just run `sudo service varnish start`

or if it is already running

`sudo service varnish restart`